# how to set value to (current page thorugh TS)pagination in ngx-bootstrap pagination?

Tags: pagination, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap pagination and I am trying to set value to page through ts file. I am setting this value from two component  and in one component value is setting and pagination is set to the page, but in other component it is not setting the value to current page

HTML:

```
    <pagination
  [boundaryLinks]="true"
  (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
  [totalItems]="totalItems"
  [(ngModel)]="currentPage"
  previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;"
  [maxSize]="3">
</pagination>
```

I am setting value in ngOnInit():

```
 this.currentPage = this.pageNavigaiton.first;
```

I have tried giving directly value to the currentPage:

```
  this.currentPage = 3;
```

but this is also not working

version:

```
 "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
```

Comment: I got the answer I have just put the condition in html becouse it is loading before the assigning the value

Comment: Can you please add your condition as answer here?
I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Shwet  Just use *ngIf which will be true after loading the data

Answer (score 2):

In your page init you can use: `setTimeout(() => this.currentPage = whateverNumberYouLike);`